# How to recieve packet sent from java program

Tags: java, python, bash, sockets, datagram

I have the following Java code:

```java
DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();   
DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, address, port);
s.send(p);                               
s.close();
```

So, this will send a `DatagramPacket` to the address at a port. How can I receive the packet on the address side using some Linux script or without writing any similar java code on the other side?

Answer (score 4):

One way from any shell (Not just `bash`) is to use [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/):

```sh
socat -u udp-recvfrom:PORT stdout
```

will listen for one packet sent to the given port, echo it, then exit. `udp-recv` will do the same but instead of exiting after one packet, loops forever. If you want to force IPv4 or IPv6, use `udp4-XXX` and `udp6-XXX` respectively, or the `-4` or `-6` options (It defaults to IPv4).

A few useful destinations instead of `stdout`: `create:FILENAME` will write the datagram to the given file instead, overwriting existing contents (So `socat -u udp-recvfrom:PORT stdout > FILENAME` and `socat -u udp-recvfrom:PORT create:FILENAME` are equivalent), and `exec:COMMANDLINE` will run the given command with the datagram as its standard input. See the documentation for more.